# Scrapy : unable to scrape nested links properly - all the records are duplicating

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping the portal using Scrapy, Here, I need to get detailed meta data about every product.
So, to get this information - initially I have scraped all the products in given page and looping through each item to get meta data. But All the details are duplicated in the CSV file.

Here is the sample code:

```py
class MyDinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name            = 'abc'
    allowed_domains = ['www.abc.com.my']
    start_urls      = ['http://https://www.abc/online-store/']

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("./csvFiles/urls.csv", "rU") as f:
            reader=csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in reader:
                url=row['url']
                link_urls = [url.format(i) for i in range(2)]
                for link_url in link_urls:
                    print(link_url)
                    request=Request(link_url, callback=self.parse_product_pages, meta={'Category': row['Category']})
                    yield request

    

    def parse_product_pages(self,response):
        item=MydinscrapingItem()
        content=response.css('.variants-pop-over').extract()
        for product_content in content:
            val = product_content.split('default value=')[1].split('>')[0]
            link = "https://abc/products/detail/?pid={}".format(val.split('"ProductExtId": "')[1].split('"')[0])

            item['Date']            = datetime.today().date()
            item['Title']           = val.split('"ProductName": "')[1].split('"')[0]
            item['Price']           = val.split('"price":"')[1].split('"')[0]

            
            yield Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_page2, meta={'item': item})


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Category'] = category[:-2]
        yield (item)


    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Here is the output csv file

[image: Output]

Comment: It helps if you post the actual result but also the result you are aiming for. Preferably in text format instead of as an image.

Comment: @Ronald , I have attached screenshot . Here issue is while updating the Category for each product all other previously calculated values are overriding

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Comment: Issue Resolved by making small change in allowed domains